# Caching HTTP reponses in a SpringMVC app

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-mvc

I would like my Spring Controller to cache the content which returns. I have found a lot of questions how to disable caching. I would like to know how to enable caching. My Controller looks like this one:

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {

    @RequestMapping("/webpage.htm")
    public ModelAndView webpage(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("webpage");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader(“Cache-Control”, “public”);
        //some code
        return mav;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have added the line: `httpServletResponse.setHeader(“Cache-Control”, “public”);` to set caching but in my browser when I refresh this page I am still getting the same status result: `200 OK`. How can I achieve result `304 not modified`? I can set annotation `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED)` on this method but will it be only status or also actual caching?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting [*14.9.1 What is Cacheable*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9):

> `public` -  Indicates that the response MAY be cached by any cache, even if it would normally be non-cacheable or cacheable only within a non- shared cache.

Basically the `Cache-Control: public` is not enough, it only asks the browser to cache normally not cached resources, e.g. over HTTPS.

Caching in HTTP is actually quite complex and it involves several other headers:

- `Cache-Control` - discussed above
- `Expires` - when given resource should be considered stale
- `Last-Modified` - when was resource last modified
- `ETag` - unique tag of resource, changed in every revision
- `Vary` - separate caching based on different headers
- `If-Modified-Since`, `If-None-Match`, ...

I found [Caching Tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) to be pretty comprehensive. Not all headers are meant to be used together and you have to be really sure what you are doing. Thus I recommend using built-in solutions like [EhCache web caching](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/web-caching).

Also it's not a good idea to pollute your controller with such low-level details.

Comment: Could you look at this one? tnx! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319915/set-the-caching-of-get-request-on-server