# What is the difference between caching via Javascript vs setting HTTPResponse header in Server

Tags: java, javascript, http, angularjs, caching

On frontend I use AngularJS "$resource" for the GET request and on the Backend I use SpringMVC to expose my methods Restful way.

Now I want to cache **only some** of my **GET** requests. I noticed there are some ways to do that like using the $cacheFactory. Or something like:

```
 return {
   Things: $resource('url/to/:thing', {}, {
   list : {
   method : 'GET',
   cache : true
  }
 };
```

Please note that this could also be a simple ajax call with some cache parameters and not necessarly using the angularJS.

So instead of on the client using such an approach, I wonder it can be done on the server simply by **Java** setting the caching just in the Response header some thing like this:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000");
```

What are the difference of these two approaches? which approach should be used when?

P.S this question is NOT a server side caching vs client side caching question, I simply set the HTTPResponse header in the server that's all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are referring to caching at 2 different layers.

Angular's cache (see [$cacheFactory](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/cacheFactory.js)) is an in-memory Javascript cache. The cache stores data in a Javascript Object. You have some control over them in the client. The cache will not persist, as in it will be gone once you navigate to another web page or refresh, unless you implement a custom cache that saves to local storage.

The `Cache-Control` parameter in the response controls the browser cache. You can't directly manipulate this cache from Javascript. But it will persist the data across sessions if you set the cache headers properly. It also lets any intermediate proxies, which may be serving multiple clients, know whether they can cache the request, reducing overall traffic more than the Javascript cache can.

As for which approach should be used when, I'd say in general rely on the browser cache since it's much lower level and persists across sessions. If you need more control over what gets cached that can only be reasonably obtained on the client-side, then use the Javascript cache. Or you could just enable both and get the benefits of both, and bear with the extra code maintenance/complexity.

Comment: thanks! in examples i see 3 different params neededed NOT to cache: Pragma + Cache-Control + Expires. For Caching do I need those 3 or Cache-Control is eneough? because I didnt see any header as "Pragma: cache"

Comment: I made a poor choice of example (removed). I mostly wanted to point out that you should look deeply into how `Cache-Control` works or you'll likely get surprising behavior. But yes, `Cache-Control` by itself works. This article looks like a useful reference http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL

Comment: We use Cache-Control to various xhr-loaded widgets on certain pages for 5 minutes.  It means that the XHR is still executed by javascript if you return to the page, but the browser itself will pretty much instantly return the cached query (as long as the query is identical of course).  I like this method as it works out as a very quick way to reduce server load on certain pages where information does not have to be super-current.

Comment: @David Thanks, removed the bit about IE8

Comment: @Woody "Reducing overall traffic" this is only true if there are proxies correct? otherwise only difference seems where the data is stored; browser cache vs local storage ?

Comment: @Spring Yes only if there are intermediate proxies overall traffic will be reduced. Angular does not store in local storage, you'll have to implement your own cache. But yes, that is the main difference, and it's a very important difference. The browser cache will be no doubt much efficient. It will also be shared between tabs and restarts, while an in-memory cache will not, but a local storage will.